# Edit and update issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New and Create are working good, data is stored in the database but edit and update is having issues.

This is my sages controller `sages_controller.rb`

```
class SagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def new
    @sage = Sage.new
  end

  def create
    @sage= Sage.new(sage_params)
    if @sage.save
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for Joining'
      redirect_to '/thanks'

    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Please fill the form Correctly'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @sage=Sage.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @sage = Sage.find(params[:sage])
    if @sage.update_attributes(sage_params)
      redirect_to '/thankss'
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end


  def resources

  end

  private
  def sage_params
    params.require(:sage).permit(:Name, :Email, :Address, :Number)
  end



end
```

THis is my view for new method `new.html.erb`

```
<div class="contact" style="padding: 50px; color: orange ">

  <%= form_for @sage do |f|  %>

      <div class="form-group" >
        <h3><%= f.label :Name%></h3>
        <%= f.text_field :Name %>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >
        <h3><%= f.label :Email%></h3>
        <%= f.email_field :Email %>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >
        <h3><%= f.label :Address%></h3>
        <%= f.text_field :Address %>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >
        <h3> <%= f.label :Number%></h3>
        <%= f.number_field :Number %>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <div class="submit" >
        <h2><%= f.submit 'SUBMIT'%></h2>
      </div>


  <% end %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', 'edit' %>
</div>

`
```

This is my view for Edit method `edit.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @sage do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :Name %>
    <%= f.text_field :Name %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.label :Email %>
    <%= f.text_field :Email %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.label :Address %>
    <%= f.text_field :Address %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.label :Number %>
    <%= f.text_field :Number %>
    <br/>
<%= f.submit 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

`
This is my routes in routes.rb

```
 resources :sages,only: [:new,:create,:edit, :update]
  get 'sages/home'=>'sages#home'
  get 'sages/about'=>'sages#about'
  get 'sages/resources'=>'sages#resources' `
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: No route matches [GET] "/sages/edit"

Comment: Try "/sages/1" or whatever id you have

Comment: Still showing error  
No route matches [GET] "/sages/1

Comment: You don't have a route to access GET /sages/1 according to your question. Please review your routes in this case.

And according to your answer "No route matches [GET] "sages/edit" you have to give an id as a parameter, see answer.

Comment: @NitinRajan - I am afraid you are getting confused. Please go through my answer, I updated it and check if it helps you out.

Comment: Can i add devise gem to the above code to give authentication??

Comment: @NitinRajan I think so. You need to install Devise and set it up accordingly. Should not be a problem.
Please upvote my answer if it helped you, which I believe it did, because you accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which URL or path you are using? I imagine you are using an incorrect URL or path.

With the routes you mentioned you should have the following access route for edit:

```
edit_sage GET    /sages/:id/edit(.:format)             sages#edit
```

So either you use `edit_sage(id)` or you type in the URL with `/sages/id/edit`. Please note that you have to replace `id` (in path or URL) by a valid `id` of a sage.

In the new view you cannot edit an object that does not exist (i.e. is not persisted in database).

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', 'edit' %>
```

is wrong as mentioned by other users.

Also if ever you want to call edit, consider what I mentioned in the beginning. Make sure you pass a valid `id` or `sage object` that effectively exists in database.

Comment: Couldn't find Sage with 'id'=id

Extracted source (around line #25):

  def edit
    @sage=Sage.find(params[:id])
  end

Comment: I mean a value that represents the "id". That is e.g. "sage.id" or any other variable that references a valid "id". Using "sage" object should also work.

How do you access the "edit" page of your app? Can you provide a code or URL?

Comment: I updated my answer. You cannot use that link to "edit" view in the "new" view. It will inevitably fail. You have to remove that line.

Comment: REmoved that line but error is coming No route matches [GET] "/sages/edit"

Comment: You accepted the answer. So I suppose it solved your problem. Please consider upvoting my answer and those of others who where on the right track, RSB for example.

Also, I would like to invite to read my blog post from some time ago: http://elyonrails.blogspot.com/2012/12/rails-mvc-architecture-practical-example.html
This explains the basics of routing, other posts explain other basics. Feel free to read and ask if you like.

Please make sure you understood the solution and why that problem arose. It could save you some problem solving in the future. Your problem was a very basic issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong, how can you edit a record if it doesn't exist. In `new.html.erb` you have added a link

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', 'edit' %>
```

Remove that line, its wrong. You can only edit an existing record and not a new record. Also, the route is wrong. It should look something like

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sage_path(@sage) %>
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"sages", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: As said by @RSB remove that line. Don't try to replace it.

Comment: @NitinRajan You cannot edit a record that doesn't exist. Remove that line from `new.html.erb`

Comment: yep removed that line but still error is coming..oh god i have been trying this for a week..pls help

Comment: Can i add devise gem to the above code to give authentication??

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to change edit link, it should be like :

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sage_path(@sage) %>
```

Second thing you can't call edit link in your new template because in this case you have @sage is empty (it just initiated),you can edit your sage by adding 'Edit' link to either index or show template

Answer (score 0):

in `update` action change

```
def update
  @sage = Sage.find(params[:id])
  if @sage.update_attributes(sage_params)
    redirect to ('/thanks')
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: error is coming- No route matches [GET] "/sages/edit"

Comment: try change `<%= link_to 'Edit', 'edit' %>` to   `<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sage_path(sage) %>`

Comment: @IgorIvancha that won't work in the "new" view, since no object is created yet.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `sage' for #<#<Class:0x4b170a0>:0x2eb79c8>

Comment: where is route `redirect to ('/thanks')`?  write correctly `redirect_to @sage`

Answer (score 0):

Like an example if you have record with `id = 2` then write url like `/sages/2/edit` and you will get data with record `id=2`. 
Do this below change in your update method also,

```
    @sage = Sage.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

The link i gave was wrong for edit in new.html.erb, removed it 
and changed the route of edit to:

```
get 'sages/id/edit'=>'sages#edit' in routes.rb and now it works fine....
```

Comment: and also @lgor lvancha